# How to remove a PATH in PHP

Tags: php, html, css, database

I just got a php script for ebooks.

This is the script https://codecanyon.net/item/ebookshare-ebook-hosting-and-sharing-script/23888795

The problem is that I want to keep the script on one site and the covers/books on another hosting.

The script allows me for the books to put and external URL **but not for the covers**.

If I try to put the external link in the database, it looks like the script puts a path in front.

How could I remove that path? ( http://localhost/eBook/public/storage/http://mywebsitestorage.com/picture.png )

Thank you
CODE:
images.blade.php
I'm not 100% sure though this is the file I need to change. :(

```
 <div class="base-image">
            @if (! $ebook->book_cover->exists)
                <div class="image-placeholder">
                    <i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i>
                </div>
            @else
                <a class="base-image-inner" href="{{ $ebook->book_cover->path }}">
                    <img src="{{ $ebook->book_cover->path }}" alt="{{ $ebook->name }}">
                </a>
            @endif
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about it but I think,

`<a class="base-image-inner" href="{{ $ebook->book_cover->path }}">`

In this section, see other available keys instead of using ->path, Not so sure but maybe you'll find another key

Answer (score 0):

Do this: 
You can use `explode` and then pop the result array

```php
<?php

$string = "http://localhost/eBook/public/storage/http://mywebsitestorage.com/picture.png";
echo getImageNameFromString($string);

function getImageNameFromString($string) {
    $explodeString = explode("/", $string);
    return array_pop($explodeString);
}
```

**output**

```
picture.png
```